# Django Form after redirect is empty after successfully submitting a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a template called `courses` for the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/courses/`. This template lists existing `Course` objects loads the `CourseForm` form.  The form successfully creates new objects.

If I go to the `addassessment` template with url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/addassessment/7/`, it correctly loads the `AssessmentForm`. I want to submit this form and then return to the previous `courses` template.  The `AssessmentForm` submits and the object is saved, but when it redirects back to the `courses` template, the `CourseForm` does not load. The `courses` template loads, the expect html loads correctly other than the form fields. I notice that the url for this page is still `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/addassessment/7/` and not `../gradebook/courses/`.

```
app_name = 'gradebook'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses'),
    path('classroom/', views.classroom, name='classroom'),
    path('objective/<int:course_id>/', views.addobjective, name='addobjective'),
    path('addassessment/<int:course_id>/', views.addassessment, name='addassessment'),
]

#urls.py project
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gradebook/', include('gradebook.urls')),
    path('gradebook/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

#models.py
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Classroom(models.Model):
    classroom_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Assessment(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assessment_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objectives = models.ManyToManyField('Objective')

class Objective(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objective_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objective_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
#views.py
def courses(request):
    course_list = Course.objects.order_by('course_name')
    context = {'course_list': course_list}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = CourseForm(request.POST)

        if details.is_valid():
            course = details.save(commit=False)
            course.save()

            form = CourseForm(None)
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)

        else:
            context['form'] = details
            return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)

    else:
        form = CourseForm(None)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)
        
def addassessment(request, course_id):
    course_list = Course.objects.order_by('course_name')
    this_course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
    objectives = Objective.objects.filter(course=this_course).order_by('objective_name')
    context = {'this_course': this_course}
    context['objectives'] = objectives
    context['course_list'] = course_list

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssessmentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            assess = form.save(commit=False)
            # save the course that the objective belongs to
            assess.course = this_course
            assess.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)

        else:
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, "gradebook/addassessment.html", context)

    else:
        form = AssessmentForm(None)
        form.fields["objectives"].queryset = Objective.objects.filter(course=this_course)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "gradebook/addassessment.html", context)
    
#forms.py
class AssessmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = ('assessment_name', 'objectives',)

class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ["course_name"]

    def clean(self):
        super(CourseForm, self).clean()

        course_name = self.cleaned_data.get('course_name')
        if course_name and Course.objects.filter(course_name__iexact=course_name).exists():
            self.add_error(
                'course_name', 'A course with that course name already exists.')
        if len(course_name) > 10:
            self.add_error(
                'Your course name cannot be longer than 10 characters')

        return self.cleaned_data
    
#courses template: course.html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <h1>Courses</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {% if course_list %}
                <ul>
                {% for course in course_list %}
                    <li><div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-3">
                            {{ course.course_name }}
                        </div>
                        </div></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% else %}
                <p>No Courses are available.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Create a new course</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form action="{% url 'gradebook:courses' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

#addassessment template: addassessment.html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <h1>{{ this_course }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Add an assessment to your class</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your assessment form at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/addassessment/7/` your sending a post request back to your  `addassessment` view function to process your form which you know. The url will still be the same as a result, which is what you are seeing.

I would suggest against returning the courses template if your assessment form is valid in the way you have written

```py
#inside addassessment view function
return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)
```

If you are just wanting to redirect to the courses view upon successfully saving the assessment form I suggest using the redirect shortcut.

```py
# add to your import
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

#inside addassessment view function - replacing "return render(request, "gradebook/courses.html", context)"
return redirect(courses)
```

This will send your request object to the courses view function. The redirect will use a GET action instead of a post so you'll just see what you would normally at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/courses/`. This will also be the url!

Comment: Works, thanks. I just need to include the namespace `return redirect('gradebook:courses')`

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad you were able to modify it to make it work 